# как поделиться google calendar через api .net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar

нужно дать доступ другому пользователю через программу написанную на .net c#

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)

Comment: от этого и отталкиваюсь, но не могу понять - у меня есть даже код в другом проекте, но по моим представлениям нужен json для аккаунта календарь которого синхронизируешь, но в коде не так - там json вроде от одного аккаунта,а календарь синхронизируется другого аккаунта

Comment: в примере, в этом блоке using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) из файла client_secret.json загружаются данные для аутентификации пользователя. Если у есть проблемы с получением json файла. Можно попробовать сделать его публичным и получать как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539375/get-json-from-a-public-google-calendar)[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1E8qTYl60xQ)

Comment: я видел что приложение запрашивает доступ к моему календарю и потом что-то меняет, не знаю как такое сделать.